# Reloading main Scene with SceneManager.LoadScene(), Scene is dark

Tags: unity-game-engine

The scene reloads successfully, but everything is dark. Even in the editor the prefabs look dark. What is the cause and workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into lighting, untick autobake, bake the scene.
Presto, your no longer in the dark ;)

Comment: yep... thank you. I guess I don't really understand what autobake does, and how it impacts perf. Will do more reading.

Answer (score 1):

Try to build your application and run it outside Unity Editor. There was an issue concerning loading scenes when game is running in Editor.

Comment: you are correct... it only happens in the editor. It does not happen when I build and play. Annoying, but not an issue impacting the final build.

Answer (score 0):

I think you change the ambient color. Toggle the light icon placed on top of your scene panel. If your scene light gone back then you have to change the ambient color or add light to your scene.

Here is setting menu for changing ambient color:

Unity 4 : `Edit -> Render Settings`

Unity 5 : `Windows -> Lighting -> Scene tab`

[image]

Comment: I see source, intensity and GI. Not sure I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Windows -> lighting -> Scene -> Ambient Source

Ambient Source： [skybox] change to [color]

and then set you want, ex: gray and white (color)

Scene will not dark.